# Solving a gradient equation for harmonic function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vectors, vector-analysis

> The vector field
>   $$\frac{\vec{A}\times\vec{x}}{(\vec{A}\times\vec{x})^2}$$
>   has zero curl, thus a scalar field $\varphi$ exists such that
>   $$\nabla\varphi=\frac{\vec{A}\times\vec{x}}{(\vec{A}\times\vec{x})^2}$$
>   here $\vec{A}$ is constant and $\vec{x}$ is the position vector. 
>   It also turns out that $\nabla \cdot \dfrac{\vec{A}\times\vec{x}}{(\vec{A}\times\vec{x})^2} = 0$, the divergence is zero. Then $\varphi$ is harmonic,
>   $$\Delta \varphi=0$$

How do I find $\varphi$? Tried to write the 3 PDEs in Maple but did not succeed to find a solution this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curl is not zero at the origin. Choose a coordinate system in which the $z$-axis aligns with $\vec{A}$. Let $\gamma$ be a circle of radius $\epsilon$ in the $xy$-plane and $D$ the disk enclosed by $\gamma$ in $xy$ plane. Then Stokes theorem gives us
$$
\int_D \nabla\times \left(\frac{\vec{A}\times \vec{x}}{|\vec{A}\times \vec{x}|^2}\right)\cdot d\vec{S}=
\oint_\gamma \frac{\vec{A}\times \vec{x}}{|\vec{A}\times \vec{x}|^2}\cdot d\vec{x}=\frac{1}{|\vec{A}|\epsilon}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\epsilon d\theta =\frac{2\pi}{|\vec{A}|}
$$
meaning the curl cannot be zero everywhere. So what is going on here? Let $\vec{A}=A\hat{z}$, then

$$
\vec{V}=\frac{\vec{A}\times \vec{x}}{|\vec{A}\times \vec{x}|^2}=\frac{1}{A}\frac{-y\hat{x}+x\hat{y}}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{1}{A}\frac{\hat{\phi}}{\rho}
$$
where $(\rho, \phi,z)$ is the cylindrical coordinates. As you can see $\vec{V}$ is ill-defined on the $z$-axis (where $\rho=0$ and $\hat{\phi}$ has no meaning), so the domain of definition of $\vec{V}$ is in fact $\mathbb{R}^3-(\text{line tangent to }\vec{A})$. But this space is not simply connected, so $\nabla\times \vec{F}=0$ does not necessarily imply $\vec{F}=\nabla \varphi$.

However suppose we still want to naively find a function $\varphi$ such that $\vec{V}=\nabla\varphi$. In cyclindrical coordinates we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla f&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho}\hat{\rho}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\hat{\phi}+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\hat{z}\\
\nabla\cdot \vec{F}&=\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial (\rho F_\rho)}{\partial \rho}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial F_\phi}{\partial \phi}+
\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}\\
\nabla \times \vec{F}&=\left(\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial \phi}-\frac{\partial F_\phi}{\partial z}\right)\hat{\rho}+\left(\frac{\partial F_\rho}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial \rho}\right)\hat{\phi}+
\frac{1}{\rho}\left(\frac{\partial (\rho F_\phi)}{\partial \rho}-\frac{\partial F_\rho}{\partial \phi}\right)\hat{z}\
\end{aligned}
$$
So your vector field is in fact equal to (naively)
$$
\vec{V}= \nabla \left(\frac{\phi}{A}\right)
$$
Can you see the problem now? Whatever $\phi$ is, it is not a single-values function. As you go one-times around the origin $\phi$ picks up an extra $2\pi$. The curl of $\vec{V}$ if you still want to stay faithful to this naive picture, should be interpreted as $\nabla \times \vec{V}=\frac{2\pi\hat{z}}{A}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\delta^3(x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+(t-z)\hat{z})$ where $\delta^3(\vec{x})$ is the 2-D Dirac delta function vanishing everywhere but the origin [Hopefully I haven't done any mistakes in determining this curl]. Physicists use these (naive) tricks all the time by the way. In their language, the origin is an (infinitesimal) *vortex*, and this vector field can be thought of circulating flow field around the vortex.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer! Then we have $\varphi=\phi=\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}$, right... ?